# Information about Aptana Studio 3's "web browser editor"?

Tags: aptana3

I'm trying to evaluate Aptana Studio 3 as an alternative to Dreamweaver CC, primarily for "production" writing of highly formatted web content.

The big factor for me is tight coupling between source (HTML) editing and WYSIWYG display. Dreamweaver lets me display source and WYSIWYG side by side and edit either one. Any other editor I consider must have a comparable feature, or at least present a WYSIWYG display and let me click it to position the insertion point in the source.

The Aptana menu has a command called Window > Show View > Web Browser Editor which sounds like it *ought* to do the what I want, but when I click it, it just opens a window in my default browser and displays the home page. I've looked for information about this command, both in Aptana's documentation and on the Web at large, but I can't find any.

What is Aptana's "Web Browser Editor" command? It it does what I think, how can I make it work?

Comment: You can change the browser that is used under `Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser`. I don't use this feature you are looking for, but for me, the "Web Browser Editor" is exactly the same as the "Web Browser" and I can't even find the command if I look under `Other...` in Views. I don't think Aptana has WYSIWYG editing. You can display the file in the internal browser at the same time you are editing it and see changes when you save and refresh side by side, but there is no auto-placement of the cursor in the code if you click in the browser.

Comment: I had some difficulty interpreting your post, so I think it's possible that one of us misunderstands the other.

Comment: Please ignore the last comment -- very messed-up user interface posted the message when I pressed Enter at the end of the first paragraph, then wouldn't let me update it when I completed the message offline.

Comment: I had some difficulty interpreting your reply, so I think one of us may have misunderstood the other.

My question is not about which browser is used. It's about a Windows > Show View > Web Browser Editor command which (judging from the name) appears to offer an editable WYSIWYG display similar to that in Dreamweaver.

I made a snapshot of the menu showing the command, but I can't find a link for uploading it. I'll see if I can post it elsewhere and put a link here.

Answer (score 1):

I stand by my earlier assessment. The Web Browser Editor view you are talking about is not a WYSIWYG editor. Aptana is not Dreamweaver. All this view will do for you is provide a quick preview of your changes without having to upload your files to a separate server. I gave instructions on how to set up your browser to use Aptana's internal browser so you would not have to change windows to see your preview of the page, instead you can dock it with your editor. Here is all the documentation I could find:

- https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-2341
- http://commonhworks.wordpress.com/ (unless you speak Spanish, you will need to translate)

All these pages will really tell you is what the editor should look like (first) and how someone is using it in their workflow (second).

Aptana is primarily for Ruby, Python, and PHP development. It has some HTML features because HTML is often used with those others, but it is not the best choice for HTML development. There are many other editors available: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&q=wysiwyg+html+editor+free

You will probably have more luck with this sort of question on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) (but I doubt Aptana is the best choice for what you are doing, unless Ruby, Python, or PHP are more important to you than WYSIWYG HTML).